# SilverStripe 3: Search Results template showing unwanted code

Tags: templates, full-text-search, silverstripe

I'm using "$Content.LimitWordCountXML" in my search results template as shown [here](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/tutorials/site_search/), but its showing results like this **"Attendance[file_link,id=214]"** when the content is a link, how do I stop it so its just shows the link text and no the code / ID? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[`LimitWordCountXML` is a function on the `StringField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.5/class-StringField.html#_LimitWordCountXML) class, not the [`HTMLText` class](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.5/class-HTMLText.html). It acts as if the string variable it is working on is plain text, not HTML. Therefore it does not strip HTML.

We can use the [`HTMLText` `Summary` function](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.5/class-HTMLText.html#_Summary) instead, which does strip HTML and accepts a word limit as the first parameter.